# How to change form onsubmit behaviour

Tags: javascript

In the HTML page, I have a form that will return false when submit, like:

```
<form id="form1" action="${formURL}" onsubmit="return false;" method="post" class="formdemotarget">
    <input id="text_name" name="text_name" value="text_name" type="text" />
    <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

Now is it possible to have javascript function to change the form onsubmit function to let the form submit?

Answer (score 1):

You can overwrite the `onsubmit` property with a new function.

```js
document.querySelector("form").onsubmit = function (event) {
    alert("Replaced submit handler");
    return true;
};
```

```html
<form id="form1" action="${formURL}" onsubmit="return false;" method="post" class="formdemotarget">
  <input id="text_name" name="text_name" value="text_name" type="text" />
  <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

It is better not to get into this situation in the first place though. Design your event handlers to handle different situations in the first place.